# Improve the info texts for the three badge flavours in the badge list

Tags: feature-request, badges, help-center, wording, badge-list

On the sidebar of the [badge list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges), there are general descriptions of bronze, silver and gold badges. As of now, they read:

> Bronze badges encourage users to try out new features on the site. They are easy to get if you try!
>
> Silver badges are less common than bronze ones. You'll need to plan your strategy to get one of these.
>
> Gold badges recognize important contributions from members of the community. They are rarely awarded.

I have some problems with these texts:

- Bronze badges do not particularly encourage users to try out *new* features, but rather features in general. And even this does not apply to all bronze badges, given such badges as [Proofreader](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/155/proofreader), [Tumbleweed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/tumbleweed) or [Popular Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question).
- I can only think of a few silver badges that actually require something worthy to be called *strategy* and that does not also apply to an analogue bronze badge, in particular [Enlightened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/enlightened). You certainly need more strategy to get [Vox Populi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/147/vox-populi) than for many silver badges.
- The text for the silver badge is a downright encouragement of gaming the system.

I therefore request to change these texts to something more fitting and reasonable or dropping them altogether, as only the text for the bronze badge actually contains some valuable information. Suggestions for good texts are welcome.